# Can someone help me with a code to change the color of the start menu labels in Project Zomboid?

Tags: lua

I changed the music and the background but I want to place the letters black instead of white, I made a code but it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```lua
-- change color of labels
local function OnMainMenuEnter()
    local labelnames = { "latestSaveOption" , "loadOption" , "tutorialOption" , "survivalOption" , "onlineOption" , "onlineCoopOption" , "optionsOption" , "modsOption" , "workshopOption" , "returnOption" }
    for _, labelname in pairs(labelnames) do
       local label = MainScreen[labelname]
       label:setColor(0, 0, 0)
       label.a = 1
    end
end
 
Events.OnMainMenuEnter.Add(OnMainMenuEnter)
```